# Show category with images in homepage Magento2

Tags: magento2

Show category with images in homepage Magento2

http://ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page

This article working fine but I need to show category image.How to fetch category images also

I am using $category->getImageUrl();

but its not working

Answer (score 3):

Here is good widget to show category with images : https://github.com/Programmingatkstark/Magento-2-Category-with-image-widget

Answer (score 0):

Check with following code.

> A2bizz/custommodule/Block/categoriesCollection.php

```
<?php
namespace A2bizz\custommodule\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as ModelCategory;

class CategoriesCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

     protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;
     protected $topMenu;

     /**
     * Category factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    /**
    * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return categories helper
     */   
    public function getCategoryHelper()
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Return categories helper
     * getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
     * example getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', 0)
     */   
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->topMenu->getHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current store categories
     *
     * @param bool|string $sorted
     * @param bool $asCollection
     * @param bool $toLoad
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Collection|array
     */    
   public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);

        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve child store categories
     *
     */ 
    public function getChildCategories($category)
    {
           if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
                $subcategories = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }
            return $subcategories;
    }       

/**
* category image url 
*/
    public function getImageUrl($category){
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category->getId());
        return $category->getImageUrl();
    }

}
```

> phtml file code

```
<?php

$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($categories as $category):
     $this->getImageUrl($category);
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }

?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>

endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

we have free extension in here: https://github.com/magepow/magento2-categories
you can use this and give us feedback about it. Thanks